# ¿Cómo insertar texto al principio de un archivo .csv?

Tags: python, archivo, csv, texto, insertar

He visto en varios sitios cómo insertar texto al final de un archivo csv y también cómo sustituir (sobreescribir) el contenido de un archivo csv... pero no encuentro por ningún lado cómo insertar texto AL PRINCIPIO de un archivo csv (es decir, sin que se pierda el contenido del archivo actual) y sin necesidad de que tenga la misma estructura de columnas. Algo así como insertar al principio un comentario. Alguien sería tan amable d ayudarme? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas! Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda que debes agregar un [example] y colocar en tu pregunta el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento

Comment: Existe la forma de escribir en cierto lugar con cursores, pero también existe una forma ingeniosa que es leer el contenido, editarlo al gusto y volver a escribir desde zero el contenido antiguo editado.

Obviamente la primera forma es optima

Answer (score 1):

Voy a dar una respuesta a la pregunta "¿Cómo insertar una linea en cierta posición del archivo?", ya que puede surgir esa necesidad (quizá querrías escribir una fila o después del encabezado)

##### Solución

No existe una forma de abrir el archivo de tal manera que permita insertar, lo más cercano es sobreescribir.

Por lo que no nos queda otra que volver a escribir todo el archivo.

Una forma optimizada de hacerlo y que NO ocupa mucha memoria es:

- Abrir el archivo original y un segundo archivo en el que volcaremos el nuevo contenido.
- Leer el archivo original linea por linea y escribir hasta llegar a la posición donde se desea insertar la linea extra.
- Escribir la linea (no olvidar poner "\n" al final)
- Escribir el resto del archivo.
- Reemplazar el archivo original por el auxiliar

##### Conceptos

Probablemente, sea buena idea que conozcas estos conceptos antes de leer la solución:

- **Cursor:** Cuando Python abre un archivo, lo hace junto a un cursor. Este cursor se parece conceptualmente al que verías en editores de texto como word o el bloc de notas. Es decir, indica desde donde hay que leer y escribir en el archivo.
- **Iterador** Un objeto especial que va generando cada dato conforme es necesario, sin cargar todo en memoria. Para obtener el siguiente dato, se debe pasar el iterador a la función next. Es posible obtener un iterador de un archivo que vaya devolviendo la siguiente linea y se encargue automaticamente de mover el cursor.
- **\n (salto de linea)** Caractér especial que representa que hay que crear una nueva linea en el archivo. Equivalente a presionar la tecla "Enter" en un editor de texto.
- **file.writelines(iterador)** Su funcionalidad es equivalente a `for text in iterador: file.write(text)`. A pesar de su nombre, esto no añade saltos de linea automaticamente. Probablemente sea más rapido que un bucle for.
- **itertools.islice(iterador, count)** en este caso de uso, devuelve un nuevo iterador que se termina luego de leer count datos del iterador. Es más rapido que un bucle for.

##### Código

```
import itertools
from pathlib import Path

# creación del csv de prueba
with open("prueba.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write("a,b,c\n")
    file.write("1,2,3\n" * 2)

# El archivo original solo lo leemos, por lo que lo abrimos en modo lectura
# El otro archivo lo vamos a crear (si no existe), truncar y escribir
# Por lo que se abre en modo "w"
with open("prueba.csv", "r") as src, open("prueba2.csv", "w") as dest:
    line = 1

    # obtenemos un iterador sobre el archivo
    file_iter = iter(src)

    # Usamos itertools.islice, que, en este caso indica 
    dest.writelines(itertools.islice(file_iter, line))
    dest.write("hola\n")
    dest.writelines(file_iter)

Path("prueba2.csv").replace("prueba.csv")

with open("prueba.csv", "r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Que nos devuelve lo siguiente en consola:

```
a,b,c
hola
1,2,3
1,2,3
```